# Using DirectInput in C# with MonoGame?

Tags: c#, monogame, directinput

I am trying to move on from previous game development languages and have stumbled upon an issue that I took for granted in my old languages. I am trying to support DirectInput in C# with MonoGame as I feel comfortable with C# to use it as my primary game development language.

The issue is I don't know how to support DirectInput controllers and dancepads. It's out of my comfort zone. I have spent far too long looking for an answer via Coding Groups and Google to find no answers and a headache.

Is it possible to support DirectInput controllers/dancepads in C# x MonoGame and if so how is it done? I'd really appreciate any help on this one.

Answer (score 0):

DirectInput is [no longer recommended](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee417014%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

You can browse the repo [here](https://github.com/mono/MonoGame/tree/develop/MonoGame.Framework/Input), mostly you will only ever need Keyboard and Gamepad.

Comment: You need DirectInput for joysticks (not gamepads)